# Am i deleting sdl2 and opengl right c++

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, free, sdl-2

I was wondering if i am deleting sdl and opengl the right way.

Here is the code of my deconstructor:

```
Mix_CloseAudio();

// Close and destroy the window
SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
SDL_GL_DeleteContext(gContext);

// Clean up
SDL_Quit();

glDeleteProgram(programID);
glDeleteTextures(1, &textureID);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, that's almost exactly backwards.

The SDL window owns the GL context, and the GL context owns the GL objects.

You want something like this:

```
Mix_CloseAudio();

glDeleteProgram(programID);
glDeleteTextures(1, &textureID);

SDL_GL_DeleteContext(gContext);

// Close and destroy the window
SDL_DestroyWindow(window);

// Clean up
SDL_Quit();
```